# aura:valueChange not firing on attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am having an issue where I cannot get a method to fire off of a `aura:valueChange` handler.

I am passing an Id obtained through Lightning Data Server (force:recordData) between components, on the final component I would like to run a query from the value. I can see the value in the markup, but the javascript method never gets called.

**Primary Component >> Inner Component 1 >> Inner Component 2 (Query Here)**

**Inner Component 2**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global" controller="AddProductInScopeToProjectController">
    <aura:attribute name="projectId" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="accountId" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="subscriptions" type="SBQQ__Subscription__c[]" />

    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.accountId}" action="{!c.handleAccountIdChange}"/>

    <div class="slds-grid slds-m-top_medium">
        {!v.projectId}
        --------------
        {!v.accountId}
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
          <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
              <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Subscription #">Subscription #</div>
              </th>
              <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Product">Product</div>
              </th>
              <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Product Code">Product Code</div>
              </th>
              <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Quantity">Quantity</div>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.subscriptions}" var="subscription">
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row" data-label="Subscription #">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Subscription #"><a href="javascript:void(0);">{subscription.Name}</a></div>
                  </th>
                  <td data-label="Product">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Product">{subscription.SBQQ__Product__c}</div>
                  </td>
                  <td data-label="Product Code">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Product Code">{subscription.Product_Code_REF__c}</div>
                  </td>
                  <td data-label="Quantity">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Quantity">{subscription.SBQQ__Quantity__c}</div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration> 
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Why would this handler not be firing? how can I run a query at this level when the accountId value is set?**

Answer (score 1):

If you need to trigger a query based on the *accountId* passed from say *cmp1.cmp* onto *cmp2.cmp*, you will instead need to use *aura:valueInit*. Any change further on *accountId* within *cmp2.cmp* will then trigger *aura:valueChange* event.

E.g.,

If my cmp2.cmp is as below:

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="myBool" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<!-- Handles the aura:valueChange event -->
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.myBool}" action="{!c.handleValueChange}"/>
<ui:button label="Press Me" press="{!c.changeValue}"/>
```

and that I am invoking it from another component, cmp1.cmp as:

```
<c:myComponent2 myBool="false" />
```

The *doInit* in *cmp2.cmp* will get the value of *myBool* as false, but that will not trigger the *aura:valueChange* event. However if you further press the button "Press Me", which say changes the value of *myBool*, the *aura:valueChange* event captures any change thereafter on *myBool* variable.